# Animated CSS text not working on Iphone

Tags: html, css, iphone

I have a Wrapper that contains a Background image, a header text and a subheader text as default.

Checking some tutorials I found how to animate it perfectly using only css3! so cool! and works fine on computer but is not working properly on Iphone. Any guidance?

```css
 #bannerWrapper {
 width: 100%;
 height: 350px;
 background-color: ;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
 display: none;
 background-size: cover; 
    background-position: center center; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-backgroud-position: center center;
    }

    #galleryWrapper {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 350px;
 animation: fader 30s cubic-bezier(.8,0,0,.8) infinite;
 -webkit-animation: fader 30s cubic-bezier(.8,0,0,.8) infinite;
 -moz-animation: fader 30s cubic-bezier(.8,0,0,.8) infinite;
 -ms-animation: fader 30s cubic-bezier(.8,0,0,.8) infinite;
 -o-animation: fader 30s cubic-bezier(.8,0,0,.8) infinite;
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 20px 60px -20px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 20px 60px -20px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    box-shadow: inset 0 20px 60px -20px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    background-size: cover; 
    background-position: center center; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-backgroud-position: center center;
    }

    #textWrapper {
 width:90%;
 height: auto;
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 top: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
 color: #fff;
 z-index: 98;
 text-align: center;
    }

    .headerWrapper {
 position: relative;
 color: #fff;
 margin: 0 auto;
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
 font-size:40px;
 text-shadow: 2px 2px 20px #000000;
    }

    .headerWrapper:after {
 content: 'Header 1';
 animation: faderText 30s cubic-bezier(.8,0,0,.8) infinite;
 -webkit-animation: faderText 30s cubic-bezier(.8,0,0,.8) infinite;
 -moz-animation: faderText 30s cubic-bezier(.8,0,0,.8) infinite;
 -ms-animation: faderText 30s cubic-bezier(.8,0,0,.8) infinite;
    }

    .subheaderWrapper {
 position: relative;
 color: #fff;
 margin: 0 auto;
 font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
 font-size:17px;
 text-shadow: 2px 2px 10px #000000;
 
    }

    .subheaderWrapper:after {
 content: 'Some small description of what We intent to say here in this banner number 1';
 animation: faderText2 30s cubic-bezier(.8,0,0,.8) infinite;
 -webkit-animation: faderText2 30s cubic-bezier(.8,0,0,.8) infinite;
 -moz-animation: faderText2 30s cubic-bezier(.8,0,0,.8) infinite;
 -ms-animation: faderText2 30s cubic-bezier(.8,0,0,.8) infinite;
    }

    @keyframes fader {
 0% {background: url("../images/image1.png"); background-size: cover; background-position: center center; }
 33.33% {background: url("../images/image2.png"); background-size: cover; background-position: center center; }
 66.66% {background: url("../images/image3.png"); background-size: cover; background-position: center center; }
 100% {background: url("../images/image1.png"); background-size: cover; background-position: center center; }
    }

    @keyframes faderText {
 0% {content: "¿Empresa vs Autónomo?";}
 33.33% {content: "¿Qué impuestos paga mi Empresa?";}
 66.66% {content: "¿Que visado necesitan mis empleados extranjeros?";}
 100% {content: "¿Empresa vs Autónomo?";}
    }

    @keyframes faderText2 {
 0% {content: "Te aconsejamos y creamos la mejor estructura según tu tipo de negocio";}
 33.33% {content: "Nos encargamos de explicar , preparar y presentar tus impuestos periódicamente";}
 66.66% {content: "Construimos un puente entre la compleja red de tramites al reubicar internacionalmente a un empleado";}
 100% {content: "Te aconsejamos y creamos la mejor estructura según tu tipo de negocio";}
 
    }
```

```html
<div id="bannerWrapper">
   <div id="textWrapper">
    <h3 class="headerWrapper"></h3><br>
    <h3 class="subheaderWrapper"></h3>
   </div>
   
   <div id="galleryWrapper">
    <img src="../images/image1.png" alt=""/>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong with my code? again, is working perfectly on computer and android devices. I thought by implementing the -webkit-animation might work but nope, still showing the default text. I mean still showing the Content:''; property from .headerWrapper:after and .subheaderWrapper:after

Thanks for your time guys!

Comment: First and foremost, you should remove the display none property of your wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Your `:after` elements do not have a `display` property. Try setting a `display: block;` to all your `:after` pseudo-elements. This should do the trick with Safari.